# What does a loop without a body do?

Tags: java, loops

Going through some source of other people's work. And I find many examples of while loops with no body

```
while(true);
```

What will that do? 
Not quite sure what the point of all that is beside making it lag a bunch?
java
snippet code

```
do
{
    if (!iterator.hasNext())
    {
        break;
    }

    Object obj = iterator.next();

    if (obj instanceof something)
    {

    }
}
while (true);
```

Comment: `while(true);` is just infinite loop in C. Its purpose depends on context.

Comment: Really depends on the context. Could you provide a bit bigger snippet than that?

Comment: i added some snippet code. the language is java

Answer (score 6):

This is the end of a do..while loop. These loops are run once before the loop-condition is checked first. while(true) at the end means that the loop will run infinitely or until there is a break statement inside the loop called.

Answer (score 1):

what you pasted is actually a `do-while` loop, which is executed **at least once** (even if the condition for `while` evaluates to `false`). The body of the loop here is what you see between `{}` after `do`

This portion in your code makes the loop a **non-infinite** one:

```
if (!iterator.hasNext())
{
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a do..while loop basically.

```
do {
  // ....
} while(true);
```

This is an implementation of `infinite loop`.

It is used when you want something to `run forever once it is started`.

Comment: Allright thanks. so all another way of doing this cut be for(int i=1; i<2; i--) or?

Comment: for(;;) too...but less intuitive than the upper one.

Answer (score 0):

This is provably equivalent to:

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
 Object obj = iterator.next();

 ...
}
```

and I really don't understand why anyone would code it any other way. It is probably decompiled C code translated directly into Java. That is the only reason I can think of for anyone to write it like that.